# Ball Collision - Collide with paddle

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a ball switch it's Y-Direction when it collides with the restrictions of the paddle. It is most likely a simple answer. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I labeled a couple of things to help.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
int Playerx;

    int width;
    int height;

    // Ball Size
    float radius = 20;
    float diameter = radius * 2;

    // Center of Call
    float X = radius + 25;
    float Y = radius + 10;

    // Direction
    float dx = 12;
    float dy = 12;
    GamePanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440, 900));
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {

                    width = getWidth();
                    height = getHeight();

                    X = X + dx ;
                    Y = Y + dy;

                    if (X - radius < 0) {
                        dx = -dx;
                        X = radius;
                    } else if (X + radius > width) {
                        dx = -dx;
                        X = width - radius;
                    }

                    if (Y - radius < 0) {
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = radius;
                    }else if (Y + radius > height) {
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = height - radius;
                    }
                    if(X-radius>=Playerx && X-radius <- Playerx + 100 && Y+radius>=800 && Y+radius<=810){
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = height - radius;
                    }//Statement Above is the issue area






                    repaint();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(Playerx<=50 && Playerx>= 0){g.fillOval(10,800,100,10);}
        if(Playerx>50 && Playerx<1390){g.fillOval(Playerx-50,800,100,10);}
        if(Playerx>=1390 && Playerx<1440){g.fillOval(1340,800,100,10);}
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval((int)(X-radius), (int)(Y-radius), (int)diameter, (int)diameter);



    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Playerx = e.getX();

        repaint();
    }
}
```

I've tried setting different restrictions and different Y-Directions but it doesn't seem to work. The Ball goes straight through the paddle as if it's not there.

Comment: You haven't really explained what is going wrong. Why doesn't it seem to work?

Comment: Just added,  Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: DO NOT USE A SEPARATE THREAD. You should use a Swing Timer for your game loop. Also, JOGL (Java Open Graphics Library) is a much better technology/API to create games in.

Comment: Do you successfully detect the collision? Your criteria look pretty suspect to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.
I realized that my Playerx was in the middle of the paddle making everything offset 50.

```
 float X = radius;
    float Y = radius;
```

and

```
 public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    counter++;
                    width = getWidth();
                    height = getHeight();

                    X = X + dx ;
                    Y = Y + dy;

                    if (X - radius < 0) {
                        dx = -dx;
                        X = radius;

                    } else if (X + radius > width) {
                        dx = -dx;
                        X = width - radius;

                    }

                    if (Y - radius < 0) {
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = radius;

                    }else if (Y + radius > height) {
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = height - radius;

                    }if(X > Playerx-50 && X  < Playerx+50 && Y+radius  > paddleHeight && Y < 715){
                        dy = -dy;
                        Y = paddleHeight - radius;
                      
                    }
```